# Django- Not able to import the file

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to import the python file `Project/MasterCard/src/Gnip.py` from the views.py

```
import sys
import os
import ConfigParser
from MasterCard.src 
import Gnip #  -- > Here i want to import the Gnip.py
```

Exception which occurred:

```
Exception Value:    No module named src
```

[image: my directory structure]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

create a `__init__.py` inside as `MasterCard/src/__init__.py`.Then import

```
from MasterCard.src import Gnip
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `__init__.py` file to `MasterCard/src/` directory.